# Find an id by filtering for the number of matching rows on a table

Tags: sql

## The setup

I have a custom chat interface that uses 4 tables (simplified here).

```
users - id, username
chat_rooms - id, name
chat_users - user_id, chat_room_id
chat_messages - id, chat_room_id, chat_user_id
```

## The Question

I am trying to find a room id based on the participating users. e.g. Give me the room id of the room containing only Luke and Leah. The only part seems to be the primary issue.

## My attempt

Assuming this query only needs to apply to rooms between 2 users (for now). I tried this query:

```
SELECT chat_room_id
FROM chat_users cu1
JOIN chat_users cu2 on cu1.chat_room_id = cu2.chat_room_id
WHERE cu1.user_id = 1 -- Luke
  AND cu2.user_id = 2 -- Leah
```

Of course this query will not give me the room exclusive to Luke and Leah. It will also give me the room with Luke, Leah, and Han as well as the room with Luke, Leah, and Anakin.

I am using an abstraction layer that makes subqueries very difficult so I would like to avoid those even if it means running 2 separate queries to accomplish the task though 1 query is obviously preferable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation:

```
SELECT cu.chat_room_id
FROM chat_users cu
WHERE cu.user_id IN (1, 2)
GROUP BY cu.chat_room_id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2;   -- number of values in IN list
```

The above returns rooms that have both users, but could have others.

If you want rooms that have *exactly* these users, then:

```
SELECT cu.chat_room_id
FROM chat_users cu
GROUP BY cu.chat_room_id
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN cu.user_id IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) = COUNT(*) AND
       COUNT(*) = 2;   -- number of values in IN list
```

Answer (score 0):

let say if you want to `limit` chat per `2 messages` for each `user`, you man consider using `row_number()`

```
select * from 
chat_users t1
    (select chat_room_id, user_id, row_number() over (partition by user_id order by chat_room_id) rn
    from chat_users)t on t.chat_room_id = t1.chat_room_id and t.user_id = t1.user_id
where t.rn <= 2
```